# Multi-Option Pull Down Lookup MS Access

Tags: ms-access, filter, multiple-columns, ms-access-2016

I have a multicolumnar pull down in a form (MS-ACCESS) with the data bound on the 2nd column. (e.g. user selects an asset from the pulldown and the form is populated with data that meets column 2 data)

[image]

I have a query that previously pulled from the default column 1
How can I modify the query to read data from the 2nd column of my pull down?
I thought it would be as simple as "[Forms]![Something] ,2" (adding a 2 to the end of the query) but that did not seem to work. Any tips?

[image]

Comment: Why did you change combobox?

Comment: What is adding `, 2` at end of query supposed to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this scenario and cannot replicate issue.

So options are:

1. if combobox is bound to column with SRV_MACID values, query should work, so need to figure out what the actual issue is and fix combobox and/or query design
2. expression in textbox `=cmb_srcbymacid.Column(1)` then query references textbox - columns are referenced by index and index begins with 0, unfortunately query cannot recognize Column property
3. don't use dynamic parameterized query, apply filter criteria to form or report - set form Filter property